# Linux fetchmail+procmail+uudeview и почта с mail.ru с вложениями

Tags: linux, email

Нужно получить почту с *mail.ru* с определенного ящика.

Получить текст в «человеческом» виде и вложение — могу.

Как сделать так, чтобы у каждого полученного письма была своя отдельная папка, где будет лежать отдельно текст письма, тема письма и рядом вложенный файл?

Делается это связкой *fetchmail + procmail + uudeview*

конфиг `.fetchmailrc`:

```
defaults mda "procmail -d %T"
poll pop.mail.ru
proto pop3
user ""
pass ""
ssl
```

конфиг `.procmailrc`:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
MAILDIR=$HOME/Mail/inbox
LOGFILE=$HOME/Mail/mail.log
LOGABSTRACT=no
VERBOSE=off
DEFAULT=/dev/null
:0 a
/dev/null
:0
* ^[Ff]rom:.*
```

здесь адрес почты, с которой нужно получать письма:

```
*^content-Type:
{
    :0fw
    | uudeview -iqa -p "$HOME/Mail/files" -
}
```

но как довести до нужного состояния конфиг *procmail*?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь вот посмотрите: http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/proctips.php#startЯ сильно не вникал, мне это не нужно, но вроде бы об этом самом.